# Group of local HTML files loading problem in Blackberry Playbook

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I have 50 local HTML files. I want to show these in scrollview or list. I tried by stageWebView. But it shows always on top of the stage. is there any way to do this. if it is possible in mxml na also, tell me...
(In mxml, i tried with **mx:HTML** but its not working in device. its working in desktop oly.)

Answer (score 1):

QNXStageWebView is a native component, not a Flash display object, so there's no way to put it in the middle of the display list, sandwiched between other layers.

Your choices are to display on top, or to display behind the entire stage.  In the latter case you would of course want to make your background transparent, but then draw a non-transparent "frame" in all the regions not covered by the QNXStageWebView.

Until the native SDK is available it's extremely unlikely there will be any "fix" for this, and even then it may have similar restrictions.

Comment: thnks peter. i tried with mx:HTML also. its working in desktop fine. but in device its not working. u know the reason??

Comment: I don't use Flex stuff, but I *heard* that that particular component doesn't really work on the PlayBook, and that the QNXStageWebView is your only real option.  Don't know for sure if that's true.